# Search for users: Only load the database when at least two letters typed, and also only loading the relevant data

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchcontroller

Im so frustrated over this issue, which i have had for a long time. The only way my "searchUsers" function work is when i put it in ViewDidLoad, and then change the .count to be equal or less than 0 (because its 0 by default).

But as it is right now (how i think it should work), the search dosent work.

What i want it to do is :

**1. Only start the firebase search for users when the user has typed at least two letters (so it only searches for the users when the user has started typing, and only showing and loading the relevant data, and not loading every user in the database).**

**2. Also update the tableview along with filtering the search.**

How can i make it so when the user types two letters, it only then starts loading the database, and only loading the right username. Say if one user types "Ma", then it will load the database (since it has two letters) and only load the user "MattGilbert", and not "TaylorSwift"?

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import SDWebImage
import ObjectMapper

class FollowUsersTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [UserModel]()
    var filteredUsers = [UserModel]()
    var loggedInUser: User?
    //
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    //usikker på den koden over

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //large title
        self.title = "Discover"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.delegate = self;

        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        //self.loadProfileData()

       //self.searchBar(searchController.searchBar, textDidChange: searchController.searchBar.text)
    }

    func searchUsers(text: String) {
        if text.count >= 2 {
            self.usersArray = [] //clear the array each time
            let endingText = text + "\u{f8ff}"
            databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: text)
                .queryEnding(atValue: endingText)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        print(childSnap)
                        let userObj =  Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONObject: childSnap.value!)
                        userObj?.uid = childSnap.key
                        if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
                            self.usersArray.append(userObj!)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        }
    } //may need an else statement here to clear the array when there is no text

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
        let obj = sender as! UserModel
        let dict = ["uid": obj.uid!, "username": obj.username!, "photoURL": obj.photoURL, "bio": obj.bio]
        dest.selectedUser = dict as [String : Any]
    }
}

// MARK: - tableview methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchController.searchBar.text!.count >= 2 ? filteredUsers.count : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = user.username
        if let url = URL(string: user.photoURL ?? "") {
            cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.userImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.userImage.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row])
    }
}

// MARK: - search methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController:UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
                   textDidChange searchText: String) {

        self.searchUsers(text: searchText)
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String){
        if searchText.count >= 2{
            self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
                return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `.queryEnding(atValue: endingText)`?

Comment: This is a question about a partial string search and has been asked a *bunch* of times here on SO and there are a wide variety of solutions. I marked a a duplicate of one in particular as the answer would also be the answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah, thanks again Jay, however got another problem with the whole thing. Posted a new question